# pagination keeps showing the same data

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have tried lots of code from tutorial but when I click on the pagination it keeps showing me the same data. 
I am using AdminLTE theme. Maybe thats the problem

Controller

```
public function view_blog()
    {
        $this->load->model("blog_model");
        $this->load->library("pagination");

        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "blog/Blog/view_blog/";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->blog_model->count_blog();
        $config["per_page"] = 2;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 5;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;

        $data["view_data"] = $this->blog_model->view_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data['view'] = 'blog_view/view_blog';
        $this->load->view('admin/layout', $data);

    }
```

Model

```
 public function view_data($limit,$start)
    {
        $query= $this->db->get("blog", $limit, $start);
        return $query->result();
    }

 public function count_blog(){
        return $this->db->count_all("blog");
    }
```

View

```
<div class="content">
    <?php
        foreach ($view_data as $row){
    echo'    <div class="row">
        ....
    </div>';
    }
    ?>

    <?php echo $links; ?>
</div>
```

When I click on page 2 the next two blog should appear

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the controller receive the page parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller:

If `$config["base_url"] = base_url() . "blog/Blog/view_blog/";` exactly.

Change 1

```
> $config["uri_segment"] = 5;
```

to

```
> $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
```

Change 2

```
> $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
```

to

```
> $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try `$config["uri_segment"] = 4;` instead of `$config["uri_segment"] = 5;`**

I would check that 5 is the correct offset for the page number of your uri segment. According to the [URI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html), 1 is the first segment after your base_url(). If you are following the defaults of the [Pagination Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html), the page number will be immediately after your configured base_url in the class. Since your $config['base_url'] is set to "blog/Blog/view_blog/", the correct $config['uri_segment'] would be 4 and not 5.

You would also want to change `$page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;` to `$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;`